# typeMismatch(Swift.Array<Any>, Swift.DecodingError, debugDescription: "Expected to decode Array<Any> but found a dictionary instead."

Tags: json, swift

I am new to Swift and I really appreciate your help.

I am getting following error:

> typeMismatch(Swift.Array<Any>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Array<Any> but found a dictionary instead.", underlyingError: nil))

Here is my code:

I am creating a ewaste recycle app and I want to use the json data and filter the facility names by the city and display them onto the screen. Line `data = DataLoader().userData` is giving the above error.

```
//
//  PhonesView.swift
//  E-Waste APP
//
//  Created by Anandika Carthikeyan on 7/16/23.
//

import SwiftUI
import MapKit


//let data = DataLoader().userData

func getCoordinates(city: String, completion: @escaping (CLLocationCoordinate2D?, Error?) -> Void) {
    CLGeocoder().geocodeAddressString(city) { placemarks, error in
        guard let placemarks = placemarks,
              let location = placemarks.first?.location?.coordinate else {
            completion(nil, error)
            return
        }
        completion(location, nil)
    }
}

struct PhoneView: View {  
    let data: [UserData]
    
    //var data: [UserData]

    init() {
        data = DataLoader().userData
        print(data)  // Print the data inside the initializer
    }

    @State private var city: String = ""
    @State private var coordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(
        center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 34.011_286, longitude: -116.166_868),
        span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 2.0, longitudeDelta: 2.0)
    )

    @State private var sortedData: [UserData] = []
    var filteredData: [UserData] {
        return data.filter {
            $0.PhysicalCity.lowercased() == city.lowercased() &&
            ($0.Excluded.isEmpty || !$0.Excluded.contains("phones"))
        }.sorted(by: {
            $0.Fees < $1.Fees
        })
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("Enter City", text: $city, onCommit: {
                getCoordinates(city: city) { location, error in
                    guard let location = location else {
                        print("Error getting location: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "No error")")
                        return
                    }
                    coordinateRegion.center = location
                }
            })
            .padding()
            .border(Color.gray, width: 0.5)
            Map(coordinateRegion: $coordinateRegion)
                .frame(height:400)
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
      
            List(filteredData, id: \.id) { userDataItem in
                Text(userDataItem.ParticipantName).background(Color.red)  // Added background to visually identify
            }
            
            Spacer()
        }
        .navigationTitle("Phones")
    }
}

struct PhoneView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        PhoneView()
    }
}
```

Here is my Json data:

```json
{
   "data": [
        {
            "CEWID": 100285,
            "ParticipantName": "Computer & Technology Resource Center",
            "DBA": "",
            "ParticipantRole": "Collector",
            "ParticipantStatus": "Active",
            "EffectiveDate": "1/3/2005",
            "PhysicalAddress": "620 Page Street",
            "PhysicalCity": "Berkeley",
            "PhysicalState": "CA",
            "PhysicalZipcode": 94710,
            "PhysicalCounty": "Alameda",
            "MailingAddress": "42 Digital Dr #2",
            "MailingCity": "Novato",
            "MailingState": "CA",
            "MailingZipcode": 94949,
            "PhoneNumber": "(415) 883-1428",
            "PrimaryContact": "Ron Berry",
            "PrimaryContactEmail": "ronb@ewastecollective.org",
            "Excluded": ["Large appliances", "Solar Panels", "Stoves", "Furnaces", "Oil Heaters", "Light bulbs", "Floppy Discs", "CD's and DVD's"],
            "Fees": 0,
            "Fees_Special": ""
        },
        {
            "CEWID": 116703,
            "ParticipantName": "Evergreen IT Solutions",
            "DBA": "(a DBA of JFG Asset Management)",
            "ParticipantRole": "Collector",
            "ParticipantStatus": "Active",
            "EffectiveDate": "3/29/2017",
            "PhysicalAddress": "37390 Centralmont Place",
            "PhysicalCity": "Fremont",
            "PhysicalState": "CA",
            "PhysicalZipcode": 94536,
            "PhysicalCounty": "Alameda",
            "MailingAddress": "37390 Centralmont Place",
            "MailingCity": "Fremont",
            "MailingState": "CA",
            "MailingZipcode": 94536,
            "PhoneNumber": "(408) 612-1667",
            "PrimaryContact": "Juan Gonzalez",
            "PrimaryContactEmail": "jgonzalez@evergreenitmanagement.com",
            "Excluded": ["Large appliances", "Solar Panels", "Stoves", "Furnaces", "Oil Heaters", "Light bulbs", "Floppy Discs", "CD's and DVD's"],
            "Fees": 0,
            "Fees_Special": ""
        }
]
```

This is the data loader (which I created from tutorial) :

```
import Foundation

public class DataLoader {
    @Published var userData = [UserData]()
    
    init() {
        load()
    }
    
    func load() {
        if let fileLocation = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "data", withExtension: "json") {
            do {
                let data = try Data(contentsOf: fileLocation)
                let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
                let dataFromJson = try jsonDecoder.decode([UserData].self, from: data) // fixed this line
                
                self.userData = dataFromJson
                
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is UserData structure.

```
struct UserData: Identifiable, Codable {
    var id: UUID
    var ParticipantName: String
    var PhysicalCity: String
    var Fees: Int
    var Excluded: [String]`your text`
}
```

I am not sure how to debug. I am expecting text of "FacilityName" to show up on my screen after filtering the items from the json file.

Comment: you are missing the top level structure. Try decoding `jsonDecoder.decode(ApiResponse.self, from: data)` where you have `struct ApiResponse: Codable { let data: [UserData] }` and `struct UserData: Identifiable, Codable { let id = UUID() ....` <--- let not var, or use CodingKeys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are getting is because you are missing the top level structure with `data`, see
the code below.
You are trying to decode an array but the json is not an array.

Here is my test code (using SwiftUI, but also valid for other systems) that shows you how to decode your json data into the models as shown.
You must ensure the struct models **match** exactly the json data.

Note, as can be seen, there is no `id` in the json data for `UserData`. Note also the use of `class DataLoader: ObservableObject` since you are using `@Published var userData = [UserData]()`

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var dataLoader = DataLoader() // <--- here
    
    var body: some View {
        List(dataLoader.userData) { user in
            Text(user.ParticipantName)
        }
        .onAppear {
            dataLoader.load()
        }
    }
}

struct UserData: Identifiable, Codable {
    let id = UUID()  // <--- here
    
    var ParticipantName: String
    var PhysicalCity: String
    var Fees: Int
    var Excluded: [String]
    
    // --- here, excluding id
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case ParticipantName,PhysicalCity,Fees,Excluded
    }
}

struct TheApiResponse: Codable {
    let data: [UserData]   // <--- here
}

public class DataLoader: ObservableObject {  // <--- here
    @Published var userData = [UserData]()
    
    init() {
        load()
    }
    
    func load() {
        if let fileLocation = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "data", withExtension: "json") {
            do {
                let data = try Data(contentsOf: fileLocation)
                let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
                let dataFromJson = try jsonDecoder.decode(TheApiResponse.self, from: data)  // <--- here
                self.userData = dataFromJson.data  // <--- here
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for explanation and for quick reply.  Really appreciate your help.